# How can I output leading zeros in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm outputting a set of numbered files from a Ruby script. The numbers come from incrementing a counter, but to make them sort nicely in the directory, I'd like to use leading zeros in the filenames. In other words

> file_001...

instead of

> file_1

Is there a **simple** way to add leading zeros when converting a number to a string? (I know I can do "if less than 10.... if less than 100").

Answer (score 310, accepted):

If the maximum number of digits in the counter is known (e.g., n = 3 for counters 1..876), you can do

```
str = "file_" + i.to_s.rjust(n, "0")
```

Comment: Heh heh, not the best answer, but I didn't know about rjust and I've been using ruby for years. Cheers!

Comment: Gotta vote this up because it seems that %03s pads with spaces for some odd reason (%03d seems to work fine).  I could have sworn C padded with zeros in both cases.

Comment: Finally switched this to be the accepted answer because it's the simplest and easiest to remember. `%` works but is more general purpose.

Comment: unexpected but easiest

Comment: Came here for how to pad a base 36 number. This works for that, whereas % looks like it won't. Thanks!

Comment: @Nerdmaster: fwiw, for me %03s actually gives a compiler error: `error: '0' flag used with ‘%s’ gnu_printf format [-Werror=format=]`... so, swearing or no, either you're mistaken, or it's changed, or.... well, at least one modern compiler disagrees.  :)

Answer (score 379):

Use the `%` operator with a string:

```
irb(main):001:0> "%03d" % 5
=> "005"
```

The left-hand-side is a printf format string, and the right-hand side can be a list of values, so you could do something like:

```
irb(main):002:0> filename = "%s/%s.%04d.txt" % ["dirname", "filename", 23]
=> "dirname/filename.0023.txt"
```

Here's a [printf format cheat sheet](http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/software-dev/cheat-sheet-reference-printf-format-specifier-syntax/) you might find useful in forming your format string.  The printf format is originally from the `C` function `printf`, but similar formating functions are available in perl, ruby, python, java, php, etc.

Comment: Great!  So "%s" means "substitute the Nth value here," and "%03d" means "substitute a number here, adding as many zeros as needed to make it a 3-digit number?" (I'm guessing the d means "digits.") I see the documentation on this now (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000770), but it's very concise and I'd like a little elaboration.

Comment: I added a link to a printf format cheat sheet.  "s" means "string", "d" means "decimal number".  The "03", means "pad to 3 characters with zeros"; "%3d" would pad on the left with spaces.

Comment: BTW - this is the same as calling `Kernel#sprintf`, which is documented here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf

Comment: Adding to @NathanLong's comment, the first example in this answer would be written as `sprintf("%03d", 5)`.

Comment: This should be the selected answer.

Answer (score 54):

Can't you just use [string formatting](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000770) of the value before you concat the filename?

```
"%03d" % number
```

Comment: I think this answer does not adds anything to @Daniel Martin's answer, however I like its simplicity...

Comment: He answered in the same minute as Daniel Martin so was probably unaware of the duplication.

Comment: This is perfect for utc_offset

Answer (score 35):

Use [`String#next`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-next) as the counter.

```
>> n = "000"
>> 3.times { puts "file_#{n.next!}" }
file_001
file_002
file_003
```

`next` is relatively 'clever', meaning you can even go for

```
>> n = "file_000"
>> 3.times { puts n.next! }
file_001
file_002
file_003
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. This is such an awesome method.

Answer (score 32):

As stated by the other answers, `"%03d" % number` works pretty well, but it goes against the rubocop [ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide):

> Favor the use of sprintf and its alias format over the fairly 
>   cryptic String#% method

We can obtain the same result in a more readable way using the following:

```
format('%03d', number)
```

Comment: If your goal is to learn an obscure Ruby language feature, then use the alias `format`.
If your goal is to make your code easy to understand, you should use `sprintf`, because it is part of the standard C-library. This name is used across programming languages. Way more people understand what `sprintf` does, compared to the number who know that `format` is an alias for it. Just because something is part of RuboCop does not make it inherently right or wrong. Pick the rules that make the most sense for your project. `'%03d' % number` is even easier to read.

Comment: I went through this same loop, changing `"%02d" % num` to `sprintf(...)`, then to `format(...)` per RuboCop's suggestion. I then decided that `sprintf` was more conventional than `format`, so  updated rubocop.yml with `Style/FormatString:
  EnforcedStyle: sprintf` and now I sleep well at night.

Comment: RuboCop's default configuration implements the Ruby community style guide (https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide). I would contest the notion that RuboCop is "an obscure Ruby language feature". If better readability for C programmers is important for your project, then it's a great idea to customize that cop configuration; it's built to be customizable for individuals needs, and Ruby discourages the "one way to do it" mindset! But, following the community style guide is surely idiomatic Ruby.

Answer (score 3):

`filenames = '000'.upto('100').map { |index| "file_#{index}" }`

Outputs

`[file_000, file_001, file_002, file_003, ..., file_098, file_099, file_100]`