# Numeric expression in if condition of awk

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, awk

Pretty new to AWK programming. I have a file1 with entries as:

```
15>000000513609200>000000513609200>B>I>0011>>238/PLMN/000100>File Ef141109.txt>0100-75607-16156-14 09-11-2014
15>000000513609200>000000513609200>B>I>0011>Danske Politi>238/PLMN/000200>>0100-75607-16156-14 09-11-2014
15>000050354428060>000050354428060>B>I>0011>Danske Politi>238/PLMN/000200>>4100-75607-01302-14 31-10-2014
```

I want to write a awk script, where if 2nd field subtracted from 3rd field is a 0, then it prints field 2. Else if the (difference > 0), then it prints all intermediate digits incremented by 1 starting from 2nd field ending at 3rd field. There will be no scenario where 3rd field is less than 2nd. So ignoring that condition.

I was doing something as:

```
 awk 'NR > 2 { print p } { p = $0 }' file1 | awk -F">" '{if ($($3 - $2) == 0) print $2; else l = $($3 - $2); for(i=0;i<l;i++) print $2++; }'
```

(( Someone told me awk is close to C in terms of syntax ))

But from the output it looks to me that the String to numeric or numeric to string conversions are not taking place at right place at right time. Shouldn't it be taken care by AWK automatically ?

The OUTPUT that I get:

```
513609200
513609201
513609200
```

Which is not quiet as expected. One evident issue is its ignoring the preceding 0s.

Kindly help me modify the AWK script to get the desired result.

NOTE:

`awk 'NR > 2 { print p } { p = $0 }' file1` is just to remove the 1st and last entry in my original file1. So the part that needs to be fixed is:

```
awk -F">" '{if ($($3 - $2) == 0) print $2; else l = $($3 - $2); for(i=0;i<l;i++) print $2++; }'
```

Comment: @anubhava if the difference of 3rd and 2nd field is 0 then print the 2nd field exactly as it is. If 3rd field is greater than 2nd, then start printing from 2nd field , increment by 1 each time, and print till the third field. The numbers should be printed exactly in 15 digit format (see my fie content)

Comment: I will try to understand your explanation but showing exact expected output data will make it more clear.

Comment: You have 2 statements after the `else`, but no braces. The `for` statement is being executed regardless.

Comment: Yes, awk is `close to C in terms of syntax` but that definitely doesn't mean you can assume it IS C syntax because if you do then even if you manage to write a script which executes and produces the expected output there will almost certainly be a far better approach if you learn how to use awk idiomatically. Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold RObbins.

Comment: @glennjackman Sorry, just revisited your comment. No need to change `v` to `$v`. I know the difference now. But still a problem remains. whatever numeric processing AWK is doing on variable `v`, it is removing the leading 0s automatically. But I want to have the leading 0s as it is the final string. How to enforce this. what I mean is this: 
Input: `1,004402146016260,004402146016300` 
Output: `1,4402146016260`, `1,4402146016270`....., `1,4402146016300` 
Expected Output: `1,004402146016260`, `1,004402146016270`....., `1,004402146016300`. Note there can be any number of leading 0s , not just 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In awk, think of `$` as an *operator* to retrieve the *value* of the named *field number* ($0 being a special case)

- `$1` is the value of field 1
- `$NF` is the value of the field given in the `NF` variable

So, `$($3 - $2)` will try to get the value of the **field number** given by the expression ($3 - $2).

You need fewer `$` signs

```
awk -F">" '{
    if ($3 == $2) 
        print $2
    else {
        v=$2
        while (v < $3) 
            print v++
    }
}'
```

Comment: FWIW I tend to think of `$` as being like an array that contains all the field values. So `$1` is like `array_of_fields[1]`.

Comment: @glenn jackman Thanks. It works for me I just had to change `while (v<$3)` to `while($v<$3)` and `print $v++`

Comment: Did you also change `v=$2` to `v=2`? Otherwise you missed my point. It is also more efficient to avoid using $ in calculations: every time you do `$v++` awk reassigns $0

Comment: @glennjackman Sorry, just revisited your comment, and found I got it wrong. No need to change `v` to `$v`. I know the difference now. But still a problem remains. whatever numeric processing AWK is doing on variable `v`, it is removing the leading 0s automatically. But I want to have the leading 0s as it is the final string as I am using this for a string match later in my script. How to enforce this, so that leading 0s are not deleted automatically. what I mean is this:

Comment: You want something like `printf "%015d\n", v` -- use your preferred width in place of 15, but keep the leading zero.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, this will work, but your numbers are beyond `awk` integer bounds so you need another solution to handle them.  I'm posting this to initiate other solutions and better illustrate your specifications.

```
$ awk -F'>' '{for(i=$2;i<=$3;i++) print i}' file
```

note that this will skip the rows that you say impossible to happen

A small scale example

```
$ cat file_0
x>1000>1000>etc
x>2000>2003>etc
x>3000>2999>etc

$ awk -F'>' '{for(i=$2;i<=$3;i++) print i}' file_0
1000
2000
2001
2002
2003
```

Apparently, newer versions of `gawk` has `--bignum` options for arbitrary precision integers, if you have a compatible version that may solve your problem but I don't have access to verify.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who does not have ready access to `gawk` with bigint support, it may be simpler to consider other options if some kind of "big integer" support is required.  Since ruby has an awk-like mode of operation,
let's consider ruby here.

To get started, there are just four things to remember:

1. invoke ruby with the -n and -a options (-n for the awk-like loop; -a for automatic parsing of lines into fields ($F[i]));
2. awk's $n becomes $F[n-1];
3. explicit conversion of numeric strings to integers is required;
4. To specify the lines to be executed on the command line, use the '-e TEXT' option.

Thus a direct translation of:

```
awk -F'>' '{for(i=$2;i<=$3;i++) print i}' file
```

would be:

```
ruby -an -F'>' -e '($F[1].to_i .. $F[2].to_i).each {|i| puts i }' file
```

To guard against empty lines, the following script would be slightly better:

```
($F[1].to_i .. $F[2].to_i).each {|i| puts i } if $F.length > 2
```

This could be called as above, or if the script is in a file (say script.rb) using the incantation:

```
ruby -an -F'>' script.rb file
```

Given the OP input data, the output is:

```
513609200
513609200
50354428060
```

The left-padding can be accomplished in several ways -- see for example [this SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543171/how-can-i-output-leading-zeros-in-ruby).